# How does C# version, VS version, and .NET framework version, etc fit together?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am quite confused by how all the parts to the MS stack fit together. How does the C# version, Visual Studio version, .NET framework version, and ASP.NET version (is this the same as the .net version?) fit together for a given project?

For example, if I use Visual Studio 2010 for a project that targets .NET framework 2, how do I know which C# or ASP.NET features I can use?

Comment: Basically, if you can compile, link, and debug on your development environment, then you can use that feature.  IFF you set up your installer to ensure the redistributables for (at least) your verison of .NET are available on your target system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C# version controls which *language* feature you can use; it is independent of everything else.  (since it's only the compiler)
You can use (most) newer language features even when targeting older frameworks.

However, some of these features (eg, `dynamic` or NoPIA) depend on features in a specific .Net Framework version.

The .Net Framework version controls which parts of .Net you can use; some .Net features (eg, LINQ or the TPL) were introduced in newer versions (3.5 and 4.0, respectively)

To make things more complicated, ASP.Net invokes the C# compiler at runtime to compile ASPX or Razor views (and standalone files in Web Site projects), so you can't use newer language features than your framework version in such scenarios.

Comment: The two parts I still don't get: 1) when you compile a C# 4 feature and target .NET 2, does a different CLR version have to be present to take advantage of the new C# 4 feature on your production servers?  2) are the .NET libraries (BCL) written in C#?

Comment: @OxedFrederik: Most C# 4 features are purely language features and are meaningless at runtime.  However, features like `dynamic` or NoPia will not unless you target .Net 4 or higher.

Comment: and when you say dynamic and NoPia will not work unless you target .Net 4 or higher, do you specifically mean you need the CLR that comes bundled with .Net 4? Could you theoretically run that code if you had just the correct CLR version?

Comment: @OxedFrederik: I'm not sure what you mean. The CLR is part of .Net 4.0.

Comment: true, but isn't the CLR, the BCL, etc all separate components bundled together to make up what is known as .Net 4? Could it make sense to talk about CLR version XYZ that comes bundled with .Net 4 on its own, or is it all interlinked with the other components?

Comment: I suppose that would make sense, but I'm not aware of any way to do it.

Comment: To answer your question, NoPIA is a runtime feature; `dynamic` is (AFAIK) purely within the BCL.

Comment: Is there any way to know these three version numbers _at compile time_? (Compiler, IDE, targeted .NET)  You can know the _installed_ .NET version with **System.Environment.Version**, which may be greater than what your code was **targeted** for at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

The C# version is the version of the compiler invoked to compile source code, the VS version is the version of the visual studio IDE, which may support multiple framework versions.  The version of the framework affects the version of the .NET BCL (base class libraries) that are available.

Thus, if you target the 2.0 Framework, as in your example, you can only use BCL libraries available in the 2.0 framework.  Thus, you cannot use `System.Linq`.

**However**, since VS2010 uses the C# 4 compiler, you *can* use C# 4 compiler features , such as *default parameters*, and still target an older framework.

Thus, this will compile and run under the 2.0 Framework when built from VS2010 because the C# 4 compiler handles default parameters at compile-time:

```
class Program
{
    public static void HelloWorld(string x = "Hi")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HelloWorld();
        HelloWorld("Buyah");
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically, what prevents you from manually adding and using a newer .NET BCL targetting an older .NET framework version?

Comment: @OxedFrederik: because that newer library won't exist on a machine that doesn't have that framework installed.  Look at it this way, if you tried to use LINQ and went to install it on a machine that only had the 2.0 Framework installed, it wouldn't be able to find the libraries and it won't run.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the table in the [Wikipedia entry for C#,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Versions) which gives you a good overview of different versions of C# language (and compiler), and the version of .NET and Visual Studio they depend on.

Remember that Visual Studio is usually backwards compatible, so you can write C# 2.0 code against the .NET Framework 2.0 even in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio version controls which C# / .NET versions you can use; you can't write C# using .NET 4.0 features in Visual Studio 2005, as the IDE was released prior to the C# version. However you can go backwards, i.e. target .NET 2.0 from VS 2010.

The versions of C# with respect to framework versions and IDEs are as follows, starting with .NET / C# 2.0 and VS 2005:

VS 2005 | .NET 2.0 and prior | C# 2.0 and prior

VS 2008 | .NET 3.5 and prior | C# 3.0 and prior

VS 2010 | .NET 4.0 and prior | C# 4.0 and prior

VS 11 (beta) | .NET 4.5 and prior | C# 5.0 and prior

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is the IDE.  It supports a number of versions of .Net, depending on which version of VS you have.  VS2010 supports as far back as .Net 2 and as high as .Net 4 (not counting current betas)

.Net has its own version based on the features of the library

Independently from each other and .Net, C# and VB have their own version numbers.  VB took over from classic VB and at last I checked was on 11.  C# is close in line with the .Net number.  These change when the language itself gets new features that are independent of the libarary.

ASP.Net has its own version as well, again, based on different features.

They are all interrelated but not dependent on one another.  Generally, they all go up a version when .net does, but occasionally they'll release new features to ASP.Net before updating the language or framework.

Answer (score 0):

A table will suit better here, but here is my answer:

> Language: C# 1, .NET Frameworks 1.0, 1.1, VS 2003
>
> Language: C# 2, .NET Frameworks 2.0, VS 2005 (main feature added:
>   generics)
>
> Language: C# 3, .NET Framework 3.0, 3.5 (actually they are based on
>   version 2.0), VS 2008 (main features added: LINQ (language), WCF, WPF,
>   WF (technologies)
>
> Language: C# 4, .NET Framework 4.0, VS 2010 (main feature added: the
>   dynamic type)

*By the way: VS 2008, 2010 can target .NET Frameworks beginning from version 2.0*